# Is it possible to convert this Delphi function to a C# Method? and How?

Tags: c#, delphi

I have been working on a conversion from Delphi to C#.  This is not normally something I deal with. So, I come here humbly to ask for some help.

Here is what I have so far:

Delphi code:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  Console in 'Console.pas';

const
  CKEY1 = 11111;
  CKEY2 = 22222;
function EncryptStr(const s: WideString; Key: word): String;
var
  i: integer;
  RStr: RawByteString;
  RStrB: TBytes Absolute RStr;
begin
  Result := '';
  RStr := UTF8Encode(s);
  for i := 0 to Length(RStr) - 1 do
  begin
    RStrB[i] := RStrB[i] xor (Key shr 8);
    Key := (RStrB[i] + Key) * CKEY1 + CKEY2;
  end;
  for i := 0 to Length(RStr) - 1 do
  begin
    Result := Result + IntToHex(RStrB[i], 2);
  end;
end;

function DecryptStr(const s: String; Key: word): String;
var
  i, tmpKey: integer;
  RStr: RawByteString;
  RStrB: TBytes Absolute RStr;
  tmpStr: string;
begin
  tmpStr := UpperCase(s);
  SetLength(RStr, Length(tmpStr) div 2);
  i := 1;
  try
    while (i < Length(tmpStr)) do
    begin
      RStrB[i div 2] := StrToInt('$' + tmpStr[i] + tmpStr[i + 1]);
      Inc(i, 2);
    end;
  except
    Result := '';
    Exit;
  end;
  for i := 0 to Length(RStr) - 1 do
  begin
    tmpKey := RStrB[i];
    RStrB[i] := RStrB[i] xor (Key shr 8);
    Key := (tmpKey + Key) * CKEY1 + CKEY2;
  end;
  Result := UTF8Decode(RStr);
end;

var myEncrypted: string;
begin
  try
    myEncrypted := EncryptStr('TheTestString', 4444);
    WriteLn('Encrypted: '+myEncrypted);
    ExitCode := 1;
    Console.WaitAnyKeyPressed('Press any key to continue ...');
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Part of the reason I am putting this out here is that this code originated here (not mine) [delphi-simple-string-encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6798188/delphi-simple-string-encryption/14989719).

Here is what I have attempted thus far:

C# code:

```
private const int CKEY1 = 11111;
private const int CKEY2 = 22222;
public static string EncryptAString(string s, int Key)
{
    try
    {
        var encryptedValue = string.Empty;
        // Create a UTF-8 encoding.
        UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
        // Encode the string.
        byte[] RStrB = utf8.GetBytes(s);           

        for (var i = 0; i <= RStrB.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            RStrB[i] = Convert.ToByte(RStrB[i] ^ (Key >> 8));
            Key = (RStrB[i] + Key) * CKEY1 + CKEY2;
            //I have a problem right here. See screen shot for values
        }
        for (var i = 0; i <= RStrB.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            encryptedValue = encryptedValue + RStrB[i].ToString("X2");
        }
        return encryptedValue;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Delphi
[image]
C#
[image]

The C# code ultimately gives this error:
Error:

> System.OverflowException: Value was either too large or too small for
>   an unsigned byte.    at System.Convert.ToByte(Int32 value)    at
>   ChronicleConvertText.Program.EncryptAString(String s, Int32 Key) in
>   C:\Users\todd7\source\repos\ChronicleConvertText\ChronicleConvertText\Program.cs:line
>   70    at ChronicleConvertText.Program.Main(String[] args) in
>   C:\Users\todd7\source\repos\ChronicleConvertText\ChronicleConvertText\Program.cs:line
>   17

In the process of researching this a few things came into focus.

- In Delphi the I have this warning: [dcc32 Warning] Project1.dpr(58): W1000 Symbol 'UTF8Decode' is deprecated: 'Use UTF8ToWideString or UTF8ToString'. Bear in mind this is in use existing code. So, I have not looked directly at what if any impact switching to 'UTF8ToWideString or UTF8ToString' would have. My job as this point is to see if I can duplicate it if possible.
- Another issue is this: [hazards-of-converting-binary-data-to-a-string](https://haacked.com/archive/2012/01/30/hazards-of-converting-binary-data-to-a-string.aspx/).

I suspect that this may be my lack of understanding of what is going on in the "xor" in Delphi verses "^" in C#. The main question remains can this be done? and How?  Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your constants `CKEY1` and `CKEY2` and argument `Key` have `int` type. So expression

```
Key = (RStrB[i] + Key) * CKEY1 + CKEY2;
```

is calculated using 32-bit values. For example:

```
(4444 + 84) * 11111 + 22222 = 50 332 830
```

is close to your shown value, isn't it?

Delphi code uses 16-bit unsigned variables and corresponding arithmetics, C# equivalent for Delphi `word` is `ushort`

Comment: Thanks! I should have known that.

Comment: When you'll translate decrypting function, don't forget that in Delphi code `tmpStr` is 1-based string

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I ended up with:

```
    private const short CKEY1 = 11111;
    private const short CKEY2 = 22222;
    public static string EncryptAString(string s, ushort Key)
    {
        try
        {
            var encryptedValue = string.Empty;
            // Create a UTF-8 encoding.
            UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
            // Encode the string.
            byte[] RStrB = utf8.GetBytes(s);

            for (var i = 0; i <= RStrB.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                RStrB[i] = Convert.ToByte(RStrB[i] ^ (Key >> 8));
                Key = (ushort)(((RStrB[i] + Key) * CKEY1) + CKEY2);
            }
            for (var i = 0; i <= RStrB.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                encryptedValue = encryptedValue + RStrB[i].ToString("X2");
            }
            return encryptedValue;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Tested against the Delphi code and it works marvelously.

Comment: Hey @Todd  did you ever convert the Decrypt delphi function to C#?  I have a come across a piece of old (not mine :-D) code that is almost identical to the encrypt delphi function at the top of your post, and am just going to start the conversion of the decrypt function